# Not able to get key from firebase

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a database like the one mentioned below. My aim is to get all the reply ids from the Shout list and then iterate over those ids in the Reply list to get the relevant Relevant reply items.

```
{
"Shouts": {
    "-KO9z16mjjr6H-03l5WA": {
        "type": "apartment",
        "name": "Regent",
        "Reply": {
            "-KO9xDuj_Dt05954Qmp0": "True"
        }
    }
}
"Reply": {
    "-KO9xDuj_Dt05954Qmp0": {
        "Name": "Arbit",
        "Message": "Random digit"
    }
}
}
```

I am trying the following code:

```
getshoutreply(callback) {
    this._shoutsRef1.on("value", function(snap) {
        snap.forEach(function(snapshot) {
            this.commentReffer = this._commentRef.child(snapshot.key);
            this.commentReffer.once('value').then(function(shot) {
                let items = [];
                shot.forEach(function(childsnapshot) {
                    let item = childsnapshot.val();
                    item['key'] = childsnapshot.key;
                    console.log(item);
                    items.push(item);
                }.bind(this));
                this.replyitems = items;
                callback(this.replyitems);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

I am not able to get Key when I do item['key']. when I print console.log(item) it gives only the values of the relevant reply. But not the key. Also in chrome I get the error "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'key'". In Firebase the error is not there but I am still not getting the key.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem with a minimum amount of code.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I am not able to setup, as there are too many dependencies. My basic problem is with the cross reference of keys in Firebase.

Comment: You wrote `item['key'] = childsnapshot.key;` but I think `childsnapshot.key` is supposed to be a function. Try `childsnapshot.key()` instead.

Comment: @PierreC. childsnapshot.key() is not a recognised function it says. Also I have been using childsnapshot.key in other modules of my project.

Comment: @PierreC `DataSnapshot.key` changed from a function (in 2.x) to a read-only property (in 3.x). It seems OP is using 3.x, although that was mostly a guess on my part.